# Make absolute layout as same size as JFrame at design time for convinience

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, windowbuilder

I am developing a Java Swing application. I have a small issue on how to resize the layout in a `JFrame` to the same size of the `JFrame` in the *Design* tab in Eclipse.

The layout's space is not enough to effectively design my intended user interface. I can add items in a crammed manner and those items display in the final output but at design time I would like the layout to expand as much as the `JFrame`. Following image would describe my problem:

[image: Two text fields one in layout other is not.]

I tried this code but it does not seem to work:

```
getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
```

This is my code:

```
public class ExployeeScreen extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ExployeeScreen frame = new ExployeeScreen();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public ExployeeScreen() {
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

    }

}
```

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Don't use "absolute layout" or a "null layout". Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. When you use layout managers properly, Swing components will adjust sizes as required. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples to get your started.

Comment: Thanks @camickr I would look into that :)

Comment: You can also call `setSize()` on a JFrame to set it to a particular size.  Don't call `pack()` (that will change the size).  Once you find a size you like your layout can be fit into that.  Don't call `setBounds()`, it's almost always the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @markspace I want my JFrame to be fullscreen so that is why I used the method setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); . Yes setBounds() seems like a wrong choice. Will look into your suggestion as well :)

Comment: @markspace `setSize` calls `setBounds` - so it's useless as the other